# multilanguage support cannot open file error on word viewer

Tags: word, language

i have a multilanguage supported sharepoint 2010 site and in it there is a document library.(english default,turkish installed later)
when i click a word document on library if my language selection is english
it gives 
Cannot open file "_layouts/WordViewer.aspx?id=/DokumanMerkezi/file.docx". 
error and the url on ie adds 
download.aspx?SourceUrl=http://portakal/_layouts/WordViewer.aspx?id=....&DefaultItemOpen=1&DefaultItemOpen=1

(... etc :  my file path)

if i click to open word file when my language for the site is in Turkish
it gives no error and open files in word app viewer.
here is the link in Turkish
http://portakal/_layouts/WordViewer.aspx?id=file... etc

the difference is as you see  in english it tries to redirect to download.aspx?Source..
in turkish it directly opens with wordviewer.aspx..
what may be needed to solve this,thanks

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like a bug in Office Web Apps.

When Office Web Apps is installed, it overrides the file links in sharepoint. It looks like there is some language selection related error in the functionality that does the overriding. Could you try enabling / disabling the "Always open in client application" site collection feature?

Comment: i activated Open Documents in Client Applications by Default feature,and then deactivated it. nothing seems changing.

Comment: i disabled both office web apps and open docs in client..Both xlviewer.aspx and wordviewer by default is opened in turkish but in english it redirects to download.aspx, i guess this is not directly office web apps related.